# Web API 2 - Communication between controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Have anyone experience with communication between controllers in Web API 2 ?? Let's assume, we are working in web zone.

Little example:

```
public class ClassB : ApiController
{
   public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)
   {
      // return some data
   }
}

public class ClassA : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(string id)
    {
       // call ClassB - method Get
       // consume data from ClassB

       return Request.CreateResponse();
    }
}
```

Any examples, class, pattern, keywords - anything will be good for start

Comment: So 2 web controllers in the same project and you want to reuse code? Or 2 web controllers deployed to 2 different locations?

Comment: The second case is more important for me. The question is: how to communicate controllers i.e maybe the layer like queue could be useful or something else to control data. Anyway, exchange data between controllers is still the main question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends if controllers are part of same app domain or separate. If they are deployed separately then you need to call ClassB.Get controller using httpclient. Ex- below

**Http Client**

```
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {                                            
            var response = await client.GetAsync("http://contoso.com/products/product1");
            var product= await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Product>(new [] { new JsonMediaTypeFormatter() });

            // Add your logic here                                 
        }

    return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
```

**Code Reuse**

If they are part of same app domain then you can reuse the code by extracting it separate class. Depending on how you designing your solution, there are different design approaches available. Example you may use DDD ([domain driven design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design)). Extract logic in domain entity or service (which suits better based on your domain) and reuse logic.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think this library also could be useful: http://restsharp.org/ .Thanks for quickly reply.

Answer (score 0):

Your controllers should not call each other, basically the controllers should only validate the input, delegate the calls to other service or domain classes then send output to the caller.
If there is a shared functionality between 2 controllers then it should be in a separate class and both the controllers will call the same method

Comment: Let's assume you have the service "Order" (OrderController) and service "Store" (StoreController). How you get information: how many products you have on your store to be sure after that your order can be completed. Before you complete your order, you have to ask "Store" about amount of products. Any design pattern ? I want remove as far possible all dependencies. Maybe my thinking is wrong or maybe exisitng any pattern or better way  ??

Comment: You can have a look at domain driven design to handle such cases, and if you don't want to use it then a domain service for Store and another service for Order and these services can communicate with each other. at the end, the controller will call one of them and the service will handle the rest